# What could cause this to start miscalculating after awhile?

Tags: c#, artificial-intelligence, game-theory

I'm trying to implement [NegaMax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negamax) for a game of checkers. I'm just testing it with a depth of 0 right now, meaning the current player just evaluates all his moves without regard to what the other player might do next. It works perfectly for about half the game (computes the scores correctly), and then part way through it starts spitting out non-sense answers.

For example, White might have 1 piece left, and Black will have 5, but it will evaluate White's moves as a score of 7 for example, when they should all be negative because he's losing. Black might about to win on his next move, but it will evaluate the winning move as a -4 even though it should be 1000.

I can understand it consistently outputting garbage, but why would it work for the first few turns and *then* start messing up?

```
private static Move GetBestMove(Color color, Board board, int depth)
{
    var bestMoves = new List<Move>();
    IEnumerable<Move> validMoves = board.GetValidMoves(color);
    int highestScore = int.MinValue;
    Board boardAfterMove;
    int tmpScore;
    var rand = new Random();

    Debug.WriteLine("{0}'s Moves:", color);

    foreach (Move move in validMoves)
    {
        boardAfterMove = board.Clone().ApplyMove(move);

        if (move.IsJump && !move.IsCrowned && boardAfterMove.GetJumps(color).Any())
            tmpScore = NegaMax(color, boardAfterMove, depth);
        else
            tmpScore = -NegaMax(Board.Opposite(color), boardAfterMove, depth);

        Debug.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", move, tmpScore);

        if (tmpScore > highestScore)
        {
            bestMoves.Clear();
            bestMoves.Add(move);
            highestScore = tmpScore;
        }
        else if (tmpScore == highestScore)
        {
            bestMoves.Add(move);
        }
    }

    return bestMoves[rand.Next(bestMoves.Count)];
}

private static int NegaMax(Color color, Board board, int depth)
{
    return BoardScore(color, board);
}

private static int BoardScore(Color color, Board board)
{
    if (!board.GetValidMoves(color).Any()) return -1000;
    return board.OfType<Checker>().Sum(c => (c.Color == color ? 1 : -1) * (c.Class == Class.Man ? 2 : 3));
}
```

---

I've isolated a board state that it doesn't like, on a 6x6 board:

```
 . . .
. w B 
 W . .
. . . 
 . w .
. . W 

w = white, b = black, capital letter = king
```

It appears that this is not a time or number-of-moves played issue, it just doesn't like particular board states. I don't see anything peculiar about this state though.

In this state, it evaluates all 4 of Black's moves as -13. If you look at how I did the scoring, it says 2 pts per man, 3 pts per king, negative if owned by the other player. It looks as though it is treating all the pieces as white...that's the only way to get 13.

---

I found another clue. In the board score method I got it to print what it's seeing.. this is what it's telling me:

```
2: White 
4: White 
6: White 
13: White 
17: White
```

Where the board squares are numbered like this:

```
  00  01  02
03  04  05
  06  07  08
09  10  11
  12  13  14
15  16  17
```

I think it is indeed saying the black piece is white...... now to figure out what's causing this.

---

So... now I know that the color is wrong, but only to the `BoardScore` function. My normal display routine never picked up on this otherwise I would have figured out the problem hours ago. I'm thinking it might be in the `ApplyMove` function that the color gets switched..

```
public Board ApplyMove(Move m)
{
    if (m.IsJump)
    {
        bool indented = m.Start % Width < _rowWidth;
        int offset = indented ? 1 : 0;
        int enemy = (m.Start + m.End) / 2 + offset;
        this[m.Color, enemy] = Tile.Empty;
    }

    this[m.Color, m.End] = this[m.Color, m.Start];
    this[m.Color, m.Start] = Tile.Empty;

    var checker = this[m.Color, m.End] as Checker;
    if (m.IsCrowned) checker.Class = Class.King;

    return this;
}
```

But that doesn't make a lot of sense either... the piece is just copied from the start position to the end position. Need to investigate what `m.Color` is... perhaps it'll provide more clues! I feel like a detective.

Comment: What game is it? Checkers? Maybe you should state it, and preferably somewhere in the beginning for better understading

Comment: If repeated invocations of this method are eventually producing different results (with the same input), it must be due to external state.  We can't see how you're Board class is built (we don't know how Board.GetValidMoves(color) or Board.GetJumps(color) are computed), but my guess would be something about its state is slowly getting corrupted.

Comment: @Kirk: Well, the only thing that should be changing is the board state. I believe I've just determined that it *is* something about the state of the board that it doesn't like, but I have no idea what. Every board state should be evaluated in the same way...

Comment: I tend to agree to agree with Kirk. Have you tried printing the board and seeing exactly what's going on there? Where exactly does the mess begin?

Comment: @Oren: Well yeah.. I just discovered a wonky board state... which I've added to the question... I'm going to try and figure out if it's reading the colors correctly now..

Comment: @Mark: GL (-: keep us updated (-:

Comment: @Mark, I don't think you can do `tmpScore = -NegaMax(Board.Opposite(color), boardAfterMove, depth);`.  If it is supposed to make that value negative, you should try `-1 * NegaMax(...`

Comment: @Jim: Why shouldn't -someFunc(...) work? I have used this construct myself before and it always yielded the expected answer.

Comment: Debugging *IS* being a detective--is it surprising that you feel like one doing it?

Comment: @Novox: I've found that not putting `-(someMethod())` or `-1 * someMethod()` will sometimes yield unexpected results.  I don't know exactly why and I've always assumed the `-` was being optimized incorrectly.

Comment: @Jim: Don't think that's the case. It was negating it correctly (I checked before and after). @Loren: No... it's not surprising.. but usually bugs are a little more obvious and easy to track down -- a Police officer could crack those cases ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your description I find myself suspecting the piece color data.  If it were somehow set to something wrong it would evaluate everything as negative.

I find myself not too happy with your BoardScore function--complex formulas like that are good at hiding errors and are hard to debug.

I would add a function Checker.Value(Color) to simplify BoardScore and allow you to view what was going on more easily.

You haven't shown the datatype of Color, if it permits more than black and white a corrupted value there would cause the behavior you are observing.

Given your latest update I would look at boardAfterMove and make sure it's being generated correctly.

Edit again:  There are two calls there--is it cloning properly?

Comment: No... it wasn't cloning properly. Good find sir! It would only break if there was a black king on the board, which is what made it hard to find. I did expand that boardscore function into a for loop and broke it into parts when testing though.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.

```
        foreach (char ch in checkers)
        {
            switch (ch)
            {
                case 'w':
                    Add(new Checker(Color.White, Class.Man));
                    break;
                case 'W':
                    Add(new Checker(Color.White, Class.King));
                    break;
                case 'b':
                    Add(new Checker(Color.Black, Class.Man));
                    break;
                case 'B':
                    Add(new Checker(Color.White, Class.King));
                    break;
                default:
                    Add(Tile.Empty);
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Only happens with Black Kings. Stupid cloning!! Why couldn't deep-copying be easier?