# Minimax / Alpha Beta Algorithm - Finding the AI's move in Gomoku

Tags: minimax, gomoku

I understand that a Minimax decision tree is a good approach to implementing an AI for a board game.  Currently, I am trying to implement a game called Gomoku (5 in a row). But there is one thing that I am confused about:

**I've looked around and it seems that almost all Minimax/AlphaBeta algorithms return an integer.  Specifically for me, the return value of eval(bestGomokuBoard).  How am I supposed to find the coordinate of the winning board?**

Here is what I have done so far:
I have a 20x20 Array of integers, representing an empty space(0), computer(1), and player(2).
To reduce overhead, each node in the Minimax Tree is a 9x9 array representation of the larger array (a smaller frame of reference).  My eval function returns an int, my minimax/alphabeta algorithm returns an int.  How do I find the coordinates of the AI's move?

And thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make two slightly different max-functions. One which returns only an integer (the score), and another max-function (e.g. *maxWithBestMove* or *rootMax*), which returns the score **and** the best move. The recursive call order would than be:

```
maxWithBestMove --> min --> max --> min --> max....
```

Have a look at Note #2 in the [Negamax Framework](https://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/Alpha-Beta#Implementation-Negamax%20Framework) on the chessprogramming wiki. A similar answer I gave [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630669/c-minimax-function/3630953#3630953).

Comment: That's why I love Stackoverflow. I almost asked a question about dreaded errors in my code, but when I looked at this answer, I immediately spotted the source of problem and fixed all, although my problem was somewhat different. Then I don't need to go asking dumb questions. 8)

Comment: I'm glad I could help you with my answer.